# object members and accessing them in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and am trying to load a data base using JS to plot a few scatter plots based on the database. There are two data bases that I want to load: one has the information I want to plot but also has an identifier for each line, and the second one has some information on groupings or classifications based on ID. The idea is to use the classification from the second DB to color the points in the scatter plot. Each ID can have more than one line in the first DB. Here is how I load the databases:

```
d3.csv('../data/db1.csv', function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x = +d.x;
        d.y = +d.y;
        d.ID = d.ID;

        d3.csv('../data/db2.csv', function(p) {
            p.forEach(function(pp) {
                var group = pp.group;
                var id = pp.id;
                if(id === d.ID){
                    d.group = group;
                }
            });
        };

        console.log("d", d);
        console.log("d.group", d.group);
    });
});
```

Now the issue is on the two 'console.log' lines, the first one returns:

```
d Object { x: 0.0, y: 0.0, ID: "000", group: 0, ...}
```

but the second line returns:

```
d.group undefined
```

What I don't understand is why the object `d` has the correct value for `group` but `d.group` is not actually defined. Isn't `d.group` supposed to point to the `group` member of `d`?

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestions below, I tried a few other versions. First:

```
d3.csv(...
    data.forEach(...
        ...
        d3.csv(...
            ...
            //do the post processing here
        });
     });

     data.forEach(function(d){
         console.log('d', d);
         console.log('d.something', d.something);
     });
});
```

as well as:

```
d3.csv(...
    data.forEach(...
        ...
        d3.csv(...
            ...
        });
     });

     data.forEach(function(d){
         //do the post processing here
     });

     data.forEach(function(d){
         console.log('d', d);
         console.log('d.something', d.something);
     });
});
```

In both I'm getting the same issue, the line with `console.log(d)` prints out fine and has `d.something` as it should come out of the post processing. But the line with `console.log(d.something)` shows that as `undefined`.

It's not just the `console.log` as well, I tried debugging it in FireFox's inspect element and added a few watches, the same is happening there.

Comment: When there's no match in db2.csv, d.group will be undefined in the second line because it never hits the if condition, and the log of the d object wouldn't have a group property.  So this is expected behavior in some cases.  Are you sure you aren't seeing undefined only in these cases?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Unfortunately, even if there is a match, the undefined shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is the asynchronous nature of javascript and the run-to-completion guarantee it provides.

To make a long story short, because loading the CSV file is an asynchronous operation, javascript will run the parent function completely before at some point running the callback function that processes the CSV file. Thus, you only have access to the group data after it has loaded (which is only guaranteed when the callback for it is executed). So even though the console.log functions come *after* the loading of the groups **visually**, they execute way before the group data is loaded.

If you move the console.log calls inside the innermost function, they will both work.

You can read some more about this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and [here is another nice article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this asynchronicity. In the actual page, I need to do some post-processing on data instead of just logging them, and then right after the `data.forEach(...);` but still inside the `d3.csv(, function() {});` I have some code that uses dc.js to do the scatter plotting. By that point all the members for `d`s should be defined right? So if I add another `data.forEach(...);` after the first one to move any post-processing needed inside that second `for` I should be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, you should be fine if it's after the second forEach, but still within the second .csv()'s callback function. (i.e. between the `});` and the `};` - the two non-empty lines before the console.log statements in your original code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I couldn't test this over the weekend. I did try a couple of different ideas based on your suggestion, but they resulted in the same `undefined` behavior. I updated my question with the other methods at the end. Thanks again.

Comment: Your first updated version is half right in that you do the post-processing where you put in the comment. But that is also the place you should put your `console.log` calls and any other things that depend on your processed data, as you don't have access to the processed data until you actually process it. Even though the `console.log` statements in your example **look** like they come after the data processing, they actually don't, as the function you pass to the second `.csv()` only gets executed way after the first `.csv()`s callback has finished.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for clarifying that. So I should just throw out all I know from C/C++ on how a code is compiled :-) That kind of solves the problem, but I can't get the scatter plot to act correctly when I add all the filtering and plotting stuff inside the second `csv` function call. That's however another question I'm probably not writing the code as it should in JS. Thanks again.

Comment: It's more the asynchronous programming you have to get used to (it exists in C++ too, but there it's multithreaded so it acts differently. In my opinion, javascript's run-to-completion guarantee is heaven sent, even if it makes it harder to actually parallelize the js engines). I recommend you read up on Promises, they make asynchrony more sane to use and seemingly more synchronous looking.

Comment: In C++ I can, for example, join into a thread which means waiting for it to finish its work before continuing, but according to the MDN link you mentioned, this won't work in JS, right? Thanks for suggesting the "promise" concept. I'm almost there with my page :-) Now that I know how run-to-completion works, I fixed the plot issue as well, it is now doing exactly what it should.